# Regular expression to replace Var=xxxx in Javascript

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to replace Var=xxxx with something.

ex: index.php?option=xyz

```
location.replace("--regex to replace option=xyz--","--something--")
```

---

Ok I found better solution from all of your answers. Here is complete solution:

```
window.location.href.replace(/option=.+&/,'some text')
```

Comment: You don't need a regular expression. `var result = 'Var=xxxx'.replace('Var=xxxx', 'something');`

Comment: @BoltClock that actually is a regular expression.  @ShirazITCo if you have what you want to replace as a variable, then just stick it in as a parameter to `replace()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(/var\=xxxx/, "somevalue");
```

Of course, you'll want to put the right regular expression for the key/value you want to replace.

Comment: Since when did `=` need escaping?

Comment: Not really in this case, but `=` is used in zero-length assertions such as `(?=...)` for example. Does it matter? :)

Answer (score 1):

Lets say your string looks like this:

```
ticketsSold=30
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    ticketsSold = ticketsSold+1;

alert("total ticketsSold = " + ticketsSold);
```

lets store that in a variable:

```
var s="ticketsSold=30\nfor(i=0; i<10; i++)\nticketsSold = ticketsSold+1;\nalert("total ticketsSold = " + ticketsSold);"
```

now try out his

```
alert(s.replace(/[a-zA-z0-9_]+=.+/,'nothing'));
```

your output will be

```
nothing
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
ticketsSold=ticketsSold+1;
alert('total ticketsSold='+ticketsSold);
```

we have replaced ticketsSold=30 with "nothing".